# IIS, how to track when the server is up or down?

Tags: iis

I would like to know if there is a way, like a logging option in IIS to keep track of when the server or a site is up or down, so that when you get a client saying the service was down, you can go and check at that time and date and know if it was the server or the site, or something else?

Comment: This all depends on what caused the server or site to go down.  An administrator stopped the site?  The server froze?  IIS logs some of this already, and for other things it's impossible to for it to log (if the server froze for example). What are the current causes of your server/site downtime?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an easy native way to do this in IIS (I am mostly a Linux admin), but I have set up a nagios installation that I think does what you are looking for.  I do routine pings and also http requests of all of my webservers (and individual sites on the those servers).  You can even set up an "expected r can geneesult" of an http request if you want to check for DB connectivity, etc.  That way Irally go back through nagios logs and can tell what it is that failed.  The trick is to make sure that you have enough local vs. remote monitoring that you can tell the difference between a server failure and a network failure.